# Next JS - Component Calling Twice On Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My component was triggering twice. I'm calling API inside useEffect. It runs once if i navigate to the page. But while refresh the page, api calling twice.

I put console inside

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Load Once')
 }, []);
```

It trigger twice while page refresh manually, it will trigger once if navigate from another page.

Comment: If it logs twice then it means the component is destroyed and rendered again. See where up the `React` tree the parents are re-rendered. Try memoizing the component to see if it avoid re-rendering (`memo(...)`).